# What is the cardinality of $3^{\mathbb R}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

I know that the cardinality of $2^{\mathbb{N}}$ is $\beth_1$ and the cardinality of $2^{\mathbb{R}}$ is $\beth_2$, but how about a different base?

What is the cardinality of $3^{\mathbb{N}}$ and $3^{\mathbb{R}}$?

Thanks!

Comment: The proof that $2^\mathbb{N}$ has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$ should be easy to adapt for $3^\mathbb{N}$. Do you remember the proof?

Comment: $2 <3 < 2^2$. ${}{}$

Comment: Can you think of a way of encoding functions to 3 as functions to 2?

Comment: How would $4^{\mathbb{N}}$ relate to $2^{\mathbb{N}}$, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$2^A$ is the set of functions $\{f:A\rightarrow \{0,1\}\}$,$3^A$ is the set of functions $\{f:A\rightarrow \{0,1,2\}\}$.  You have an injection $2^{\mathbb{N}}\rightarrow 3^{\mathbb{N}}$ which sends the application $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \{0,1\}$ to $i\circ f$ where $i:\{0,1\}\rightarrow\{0,1,2\}$ is the canonical embedding defined by $i(0)=0,i(1)=1$. You deduce that $|2^{\mathbb{N}}\leq |3^{\mathbb{N}}|$.

On the other side, you can define $h:3^{\mathbb{N}}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $h(f)$ is the decimal number $0.f(0)f(1).....f(n)...$, $h$ is injective. This implies that $|3^{\mathbb{N}}|\leq |\mathbb{R}|=|2^{\mathbb{N}}$. We deduce that $|2^{\mathbb{N}}|=|3^{\mathbb{N}}|=|\mathbb{R}|$.